# What is the right place to ask about web applications' desktop software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, etiquette, site-crossover

Google Backup and Sync is completely undocumented software, so Stack Exchange seems like a good place to ask questions especially strictly like **"what happens when you tick this option?"**.

The problem is where to ask. As it's desktop software, it's against the rules of *Web Applications*, even though its purpose is to interact with a web application (both Google Drive and Google Photos).

But as soon I tried to ask [such a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1425844/) on Super User, I was immediately encountered with hostile comments ("How about you do as instructed", which BTW, I did), got points dropped and had my question paused (one of the voters also wrote a comment that explained about Google's quota that had no relation to the question). It doesn't make me want to ask any more related questions there.

Is Stack Exchange just not a place to ask about web applications' desktop software, or is there a more fitting place than Web Applications and Super User?

Comment: Well, your question was actually three questions, and on this network of sites, we expect questions to just ask one question (or else they get marked "too broad"). The first question was on-topic (about the desktop software), but the second wasn't, and I couldn't tell if the third was.

Comment: My question here was just 1 question yet points were dropped in less than 2 seconds, why? If I were to divide my questions there into 3 different topics, will it be okay? Are you sure they won't flag it 3 times and drop points 3 times?

Comment: Also, the second question is just a continuance of "what if I tick this option?" question. I've just deleted the third one if you so feel it's off-topic.

Comment: After more closely reading the two questions, they are indeed inter-related, but it results in confusion from users who think you're asking multiple distinct questions. You should rephrase it so it reads like just one question.

Comment: I feel the third one was inter-related too, but I've dropped it anyway to avoid any risk. Can you help me rephrase? Meanwhile, why are points constantly dropped here? As you can see, you and I politely converse with each other. What is so terrible about this question?

Comment: I've proposed an edit to that post so that it's clear to others that they are inter-related enough (and not distinct enough to be too broad). Also, as far as downvotes here, people tend to be subjective with them on this site (e.g. downvoting feature requests they disagree with despite them being well-written and on-topic), so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: I've accepted your edit, thanks!!! Do you know what can be done about the question's status now? Meanwhile, points are a central feature of StackExchange, so ignoring them is a bit against what StackExchange proudly stands for. What happens here now and in the Superuser question pushes potential submitters away.

Comment: FYI, I was referring to the downvotes *here* (on *this site*, Meta.SE), not Super User. The edits will place your question into a queue for potential reopening; if users in the queue deem them insufficient to allow for reopening, you can raise a question on their meta, [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com).

Answer (score 4):

> What is the right place to ask about web applications' desktop software?

Super User or Web Applications spring to mind.

> Stack Exchange seems like a good place to ask questions especially strictly like "what happens when you tick this option?".

No, not really.
We're not a tutorial site or a replacement for software companies that can't be bothered to document their stuff.

You're free to ask about the result of you ticking that self-destruct option and then ask about the disappointing result.

> The problem is where to ask. As it's desktop software, it's against the rules of *Web Applications*, even though its purpose is to interact with a web application (both Google Drive and Google Photos).

Hmm. Based on a quick search both Super User and [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+backup) seem to take such questions. You can ask on the per-site meta if your question is on-topic. It is shown I'm not familiar with the scope Webapps as I just learned questions about that tool are off-topic there.

> But as soon I tried to ask such a question on Super User, I was immediately encountered with hostile comments ("How about you do as instructed", which BTW, I did), got points dropped and had my question paused (one of the voters also wrote a comment that explained about Google's quota that had no relation to the question). It doesn't make me want to ask any more related questions there.

I don't see any hostile comments, to be honest or some must have been deleted. Don't mistake comments that are to the point for being hostile. You're free to not like that tone but please stop calling everything that doesn't come with an emoticon hostile. Asking *"How about you do as instructed"* was meant to invite you to provide more details to be added to your question. You answered in a comment. Make an edit to include that comment of yours in your question.

> Is Stack Exchange just not a place to ask about web applications' desktop software, or is there a more fitting place than Web Applications and Super User?

It depends. Both sites could work, if the question doesn't sound too much hypothetical or *explain how this works*. For example your title could be

> Why didn't the Google Backup & Sync desktop app honor the "Upload photos and videos to Google Photos”

and then explain in your question what you did expect that option to do and what it did instead. Maybe provide information on what made you think that option applied to your use case.

Comment: The "Backup and Sync" application is not a web application, so is off-topic at Web Applications.

Comment: @ale my assumption was that client tools that interact with what is basically a webapp would be on-topic, and I assumed Backup and Sync was such a tool. I stand corrected. I've edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: This debate proves the answer is far from obvious. So why are points keep getting dropped here?